# If two rows have same id but different col2, how can you keep only the ones that have max col3?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table with three columns (id, col2, col3, col4) where col2 is A or B and col3 and col4 are integers. My problem is, there are many columns that have the same id and a different col2 value, and I want to select ONLY the rows that have a maximum value in col3.

For instance, if we have:

```
id | col2 | col3 | col4
1  |  A   |  3   |  2
1  |  B   |  5   |  3
2  |  A   |  6   |  2
...
```

I want to keep only the tuple (1, B, 5, 3). How can I achieve this?

I've tried this:

```
SELECT id, col2, MAX(col3), col4 FROM t GROUP BY id;
```

but I get an error saying that this is not a valid GROUP BY statement.

Comment: When you say "keep only ..." - what do you mean by that? Do you want to `delete` rows from the table? Or do you just mean in a **report** (technically, in a SQL `select` statement)? The two different interpretations are very different. Then, if you have several rows for a single ID, but two or more (or even all of them) have the same highest value in `col3`, what do you want to keep? ALL those rows (with the max value in `col3`)? Or just one of them - and then, which one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keep`:

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(col2) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY col3 DESC) as col2
       MAX(col3),
       MAX(col4) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY col3 DESC) as col4
FROM t
GROUP BY id;
```

Or:

```
SELECT id, col2, col3, col4
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY col3 DESC) as seqnum
      FROM t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t inner join (
  select id, max(col3) col3
  from tablename
  group by id
  having count(distinct col2) > 1
) g on g.id = t.id and g.col3 = t.col3
```

returns for each `id` that has different values in `col2` only 1 row: the one containing the maximum value of `col3`.
If you also want the other rows where each `id` does not have different values in `col2`, then use `UNION ALL`:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t inner join (
  select id, max(col3) col3
  from tablename
  group by id
  having count(distinct col2) > 1
) g on g.id = t.id and g.col3 = t.col3
union all
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id = t.id and col2 <> t.col2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from TableName where col3 = (select max(col3) from TableName)